# Django: forms.ChoiceField, overriding forms __init__

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, choicefield

I am trying to implement a forms.ChoiceField() with values from a view.
I already can do it if I declare the choices in the forms.py, but that's not what I need.

views.py:

```
def add_crime(request):
        values = [('1','um'),('2','dois'),('3','tres')]
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AddCrimeForm(request.POST, values)
            if form.is_valid():
                # do stuff
                return redirect('show_crime')
        else:
            form = AddCrimeForm(request.GET)
        return render(request, 'add_crime.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class AddCrimeForm(forms.Form):
    tests = forms.ChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, testList, args, **kwargs):
        self.testList = testList
        super(AddCrimeForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # testList not in args!
        self.fields['tests'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['tests'].choices = self.testList
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

From the feedback, do I have to implement another `__init__` with one argument in forms.py? That's what I would try in Java.

My final goal is to implement two ChoiceField and the second one would depend from the first one. Is there a better way?

Comment: The first parameter of your `AddCrimeForm` should here be the `values`. You also forgot to add an asterisks for the `*args`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes here: the first one is in the `AddCrimeForm`. Here `*args` in the `__init__` header needs an asterisk (`*`):

```
class AddCrimeForm(forms.Form):

    tests = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, testList, *args, **kwargs):
        self.testList = testList
        super(AddCrimeForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # testList not in args!
        self.fields['tests'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['tests'].choices = self.testList
```

You also probably want to make `forms` a [**`MultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) if you want to select *multiple* choices.

In your view, you should construct an `AddCrimeForm`, with the list of `values` as *first* element, since it is defined as first element in your `AddCrimeForm`:

```
def add_crime(request):
        values = [('1','um'),('2','dois'),('3','tres')]
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AddCrimeForm(values, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # do stuff
                return redirect('show_crime')
        else:
            form = AddCrimeForm(values)
        return render(request, 'add_crime.html', {'form': form})
```

Unless you want to handle the *querystring* in your form, one typically does not pass `request.GET` to the form, since otherwise it will take values that are defined in the querystring.